# Criar select para uma tabela em PHP

Tags: php, sql, select, mvc

Estou com problemas ao criar o `select` para posteriormente usar numa tabela.

As tabelas SQL obrigatórias são as seguintes:

```
“Aluno” (**PK:** id, numero, nome), 
“Area” (**PK:** id, nome), 
“UC” (**PK:** id, nome, **FK:** id_area) 
“Classificacao”
    (
      **PK:** id, 
      **FK:** id_uc, 
      **FK:** id_aluno,
      nota
    )
```

Objectivo é criar uma tabela em php (mvc) da seguinte forma:

[image: Tabela final]

1. Coluna - Nº aluno
2. Coluna - Nome do aluno
3. Coluna - Nº disciplinas do aluno na área 1
4. Coluna - Nº disciplinas do aluno na área 2
5. Coluna - Se soma disciplinas for maior ou igual que 6 "Sim" (Admitido)

Com as entidades e relações que existem entre as tabelas, que `select` tenho de fazer ao *SQL* para preencher a tabela?

Actualmente tenho o esqueleto *MVC* e `select` da tabela classificação

```
function getClassificacao()
{
    $classificacao = array();

    $db=new db();
    $con=$db->connect();

    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM classificacao";
    $result = $con->query($sql_query);

    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $classificacao[$i]["id"] = $row["id"];
        $classificacao[$i]["id_uc"] = $row["id_uc"];
        $classificacao[$i]["id_aluno"] = $row["id_aluno"];
        $classificacao[$i]["nota"] = $row["nota"];
        $i++;
    }
    return $classificacao;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes utilizar uma `query`como esta:

```
SELECT aluno.nome AS 'Nome Aluno', aluno.numero AS 'Numero Aluno', area.nome AS 'Área', COUNT(area.id) AS 'Disciplinas da Área' FROM aluno INNER JOIN classificacao ON aluno.id = classificacao.id_aluno INNER JOIN uc on classificacao.id_uc = uc.id INNER JOIN area ON uc.id_area = area.id WHERE aluno.id = 1 GROUP BY area.id, aluno.nome;
```

Isto retorna um resultado como

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Penso que ser isto que queres. Depois é manipular do lado do PHP / HTML

Comment: Estou agradecido, alguém consegue separar por vários selects?

Comment: Pq varios selects? Você entendeu pelo menos a logica?

Comment: O problema é mesmo esse, não entendi a lógica, pretendo dividir por sub selects com objectivo de entender e usar posteriormente.